# Angular: Formatting numbers with commas

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Title very much sums up my needs.

```
123456789 => 123,456,789
12345 => 12,345
```

What's the best way to get this conversion ? Don't suggest currency pipe in Angular-2 as I don't need $ or currency symbol to be prepend to my output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: @gforce301 It's a different enviroment, the op wanted a solution for angular2 too, as CodeWarrior answered with a pipe solution.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use DecimalPipe like this

`{{attr | number}}`

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzE5NOoytQu2yxD6)

Documentation available at https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Answer (score 18):

```js
function printNo() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML =
  Number(1234355).toLocaleString('en-GB');
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head></head>
    
     <body onload="printNo()">
      <h1 id="text"></h1>
        
     </body>
</html>
```

[Reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: this is amazing..

Answer (score 15):

Without using pipes, a simple way to answer your question with javascript:

```
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.".replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1,");
```

And this will output `Th,e ,qu,ic,k ,br,ow,n ,fo,x ,ju,mp,s ,ov,er, t,he, l,az,y ,do,gs,.`

But I think you formulated your question bad, so, If you want to parse numbers, you should use this function:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

So

```
var num = numberWithCommas(1234567);
console.log(num);
```

This will output `1,234,567`

Answer (score 5):

CodeWarrior's answer on pipes works great for front-end display.  Recommended if your number is easy to isolate and pipe in your HTML.  Sometimes though, it is much more convenient to get the formatted number in Typescript/Javascript before assembling something for display.

**For Typescript in Angular**, `formatNumber()` from @angular/common will comma separate numbers.  With `num` as a string of "12345":

`formatNumber(Number(num), 'en-US', '1.0-0')`

will produce "12,345" as another string.  Obviously different locales will format the number differently ('en-US' uses ',' and '.'), and the third option of digitsInfo can define whether your want decimals or not ('1.0-0' suggests one digit before '.' and zero after).

You will need to import formatNumber with

`import {formatNumber} from '@angular/common';`

Documentation at https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber

Comment: Oh cool, I did not know about this! Do you know if/how it would be possible to visualise the formatted output inside the input field?