# Angular - Automatically add Commas to a Number in a Inputbox?

Tags: html, angular

I want to Automatically add Commas to a Number in a Input Box in Angular.

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="buttons">
   <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickData(product.button1)">{{product.button1}}</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickData(product.button2)">{{product.button2}}</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickData(product.button3)">{{product.button3}}</button>
      <button [ngClass]="product.button4 === '=' ? 'btn-blue btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1'" type="button" (click)="clickData(product.button4)">{{product.button4}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 clickData(num: string){

if (num=="0") {
  if (this.input !="" ) {

    const lastNum=this.getLastOperand()
    if (lastNum.lastIndexOf("0") >= 0) return;
  }
}

if (num=="0") {
  if (this.input=="" ) {
    return;
  }
  const PrevKey = this.input[this.input.length - 1];
  if (PrevKey === '/' || PrevKey === '*' || PrevKey === '-' || PrevKey === '+')  {
      return;
  }
}

this.input = this.input + num

console.warn("op",this.input)

this.closebutton.nativeElement.click();

}
```

The above code is **Html** file and **.ts** file. I want when I click on button which is 00 button it will automatically add comma. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want set comma when the focus change or while typing?

Comment: do you mean you automatically want to format a number to display comma separators at the thousand, million, etc? (i.e. like: 1,000,000)

Comment: @blurfus yes I want exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: Formatting numbers with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929282/angular-formatting-numbers-with-commas)

Comment: @blurfus can i do with this `<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickData(product.button2)">{{product.button2 === '00' ? (product.button2 | number) : product.button2}}</button>`?

Comment: @blurfus I got the solution thanks for the your suggestion.

Comment: It’s community’s best practice to post the answer (even if you came up with it yourself) so others in the community asking the same question can find it.

Answer (score 0):

so as you said want to add the commas to number below is the solutions

**in .ts file**

```
InputOnchange(value) {
    const replace = value.replace(/,/g, '');
    const number = parseInt(replace);
    this.value = number;
   
  }

processMyValue(amount) {
    if (isNaN(amount) || amount === null || amount === '') {
      return amount;
    } else {
      const replace = amount.replace(/,/g, '');
      const number = parseInt(replace);
    }    
  }
```

**in .html file**

```
     <mat-form-field >
<mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
                                    <input (input)="InputOnchange($event.target.value)" autocomplete="off"
                                        matInput placeholder="Amount "
                                        formControlName="amount_Amount" required
                                        (wheel)="$event.preventDefault()"
                                        (focusout)="processMyValue($event.target.value)"
                                        />
                                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I got the solution thanks for the your suggestion.